# Can not insert a figure in the text

Tags: floats

This may be a very rudimentary question, but I am new to LaTeX and trying to learn. 
When I want to inset a pdf image in LaTeX through the Insert menu in TeXnicCenter, I get the following warning:

```
File 'Directory of file' not fount on input line ...
```

However, The image appears in the output file, but the path to where the image is located is also appearing above the figure in the output file. 
Its really frustrating! please help.

Comment: Give a small example of how you input your file  to your document

Comment: Check if spaces are present in the path to the image and avoid those spaces.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It is considered a lot better to put in some code that will compile, as it makes it a lot easier for us to copy it into our text editor and work with it, and see exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Dear all, I fixed the problem by including the image in the working directory of latex and then just mentioning the name of the image in the figure statement instead of its full path. It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by including the image in the working directory of latex and then just mentioning the name of the image in the figure statement instead of its full path. It worked perfectly. 
Thank you very much for your help and condensation